# Cucumber Example Table Not Delimiting Properly

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have an example table

```
Examples:
| UserName         | Group    | NotifyUser | ReadOnlyPermission |
| testing@test.com | new test | no         | no                 |
```

for the step

```
And User fills out User Info Form with <UserName> <Group> <NotifyUser> <ReadOnlyPermission>
```

and the step definition of

```
@And("^User fills out User Info Form with (.*) (.*) (.*) (.*) $")
public void fillUserInfoForm(String username, String group, String notifyUser, String readOnlyPermission)
```

But for some reason the variable username is being imported as "testing@test.com new" instead of just "testing@test.com".

I've looked all over but I can't seem to find out why its not delimiting correctly. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becasue you have whitespace in your "Group". After Cucumber substities your example data to the step it looks like:

[image]

You can rewrite your step definition to separate your items with say comma, so that:

```
And User fills out User Info Form with <UserName>,<Group>,<NotifyUser>,<ReadOnlyPermission>
```

and

```
@And("^User fills out User Info Form with (.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)$")
public void fillUserInfoForm(String username, String group, String notifyUser, String readOnlyPermission)
```

This should resolve your issue:

[image]

**P.S.** - This fix will encounter problems if you have commas in your example data. However you can consider this when prepare your regular expressions.

Comment: So why was it that username came through as "testing@test.com new" instead of "new" becoming its own item and ending up with "testing@test.com" "new" "test"?

Comment: Because you had fixed number of whitespaces between capturing groups but you're not limited with spaces inside groups (since a dot accepts all the symbols including spaces). This is why such "unexpected" grouping was the only matching the expression you had originally.